# Настройка grid формы

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть 4 поля Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Дата рождения.
Не получается настроить стиль таким образом чтобы они верно отображались на странице.

нужно чтобы когда страница раскрыты полностью формы выстраивались как 1 2 3 4.

когда страницу сжимаешь они бы перестраивались.

1 2

3 4

сейчас сделано так

```
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    grid-gap: 20px 50px;
}

.grid-item {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 250px;
}
<h:panelGroup id="holder_panel" layout="block">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item">some code</div>
      <div class="item">some code</div>
      <div class="item">some code</div>  
      <div class="item">some code</div>  
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

и проблема вот в чем.

когда страница развернута, все ок.

а когда сжимаешь ее, то при вводе в поле 1 неверное информации строка снизу смещает поле 3 в сторону. см рисунок во вложении. отчество съехало[image: пример]

```
1 2

  3

4
```

как настроить форму?

Comment: необходим полный код, а также какая версия bootstrap используется?

Comment: полный код страницы очень большой. bootstrap 3..3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для бутстрапа 3 версии переменное число колонок делается так:

на мобилках будет

```
1
2
3
4
```

на планшетах

```
1 2
3 4
```

на десктопах

```
1 2 3 4
```

код:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Фамилия</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Фамилия">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Имя">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="secondName">Отчество</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondName" placeholder="Отчество">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="birthDate">Дата рождения</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthDate" placeholder="Дата рождения">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Дополнено:

> если добавить ошибку валидации (любой текст) - такая же проблема будет – soledar10

Можно применить flex, чтобы увеличение высоты блока из-за текста об ошибке меняло и высоту соседа

```
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-row .col-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-row .col-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
    margin: -.3px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}


<div class="row row-flex">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-flex">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если добавить ошибку валидации (любой текст) - такая же проблема будет

Comment: дополнил ответ. можно "поиграться" с flex

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  [class*=col-]:nth-of-type(2n + 3) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Фамилия</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Фамилия">
      <p>Error validation</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">Имя</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="secondName">Отчество</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondName" placeholder="Отчество">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="birthDate">Дата рождения</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthDate" placeholder="Дата рождения">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```